# Inject code to the <head> tag of the TinyMCE iframe on WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, tinymce, hook

Is it possible to inject code to the TinyMCE WordPress editor via hooks? Specifically, I want to insert code within the `<head>` tag of the `<iframe>`. Something similar to the `add_action( 'wp_head', 'function_name' )`.

The content I'll add is a dynamically generated CSS (based on an `ACF Options Page` repeater field). I tried to create a `*.php` file with `header("Content-type: text/css")` header in it + the CSS content and then use the `add_editor_style()` function but when I call the file in a `href` attribute it seems like the WordPress functions (including ACF's `get_field()`) are not defined.

I also tried using data URI strings like `data:text/css,.color_1{color:...` but `add_editor_style()` ignores invalid URLs.

Comment: I have to mention that the CSS classes are generated dynamically too, following this structure: `.color_{$index} { color:...`.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this to add CSS that will impact how the content in TinyMCE is rendered?

Comment: Yes, merely for WYSIWYG purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two settings in the TinyMCE configuration that you can use to pass CSS to the editor:

- `content_css`

  - https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css
- `content_style`

  - https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_style

You can use the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter (via `add_filter`) to inject CSS into the editor using one of these configuration options.

As a WordPress plugin would be running in PHP perhaps you could process the needed CSS into a string on the server and pass it in via `content_style`?